# how to pull mysql data using .ajax and populating a form with it

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a field on a from that a user creates a return code. the form data is stored in a MySQL database and if that user comes back and users the same return code it will pull the record from the database and full most of the data base in to save the user time. I am not sure how to do this. I am using MySQL and PHP for the database and i don't know how to use .ajax in JavaScript to make the pull or how to take that data and fill the form.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David is referring to, using the jquery ajax api might make it easier for you.  So your client side code might look something like:

```
var request = $.ajax(url: 'your_php_script.php', 
                     datatype: 'json',
                     success: function() {
                     request = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);

                     ...The rest of your javascript code to read the 
                     ...json and fill in the form.
                     ...
               });
```

Here's a helpful [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, encode the data with JSON via `json_encode()`, then `$.get` it on the client-side. You can then access the data as any other JSON object. To set a form value, you'd do `$('#formfield').val( myobj.property1 );`